# Vim: What's the difference between let and set?

Tags: vim

What's the difference between `let` and `set` in the vim editor?

I've always wondered why both of them exist?

Also, I'd be interested to hear its historical background.

Comment: Did you try `:help set` and `:help let` and read the manual?

Comment: yes I did that, but I still don't get why set has to exist, because let does the same things.

Comment: @DavidHalter: `let` does not do the same things. There are things you cannot achieve with `set` that are possible with `let`, see my answer.

Comment: No one has mentioned `setlocal` yet... they are equivalent to `&l:*` variables.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger That still doesn't justify the existence of `set` -- all you said is that `let` can do things `set` cannot, but can `set` do things `let` can't? Unless there are disjunctive features, one of the commands is unnecessary.

Comment: @VictorZamanian: for boolean settings, it's arguably easier to just `set noic` or `set ic`. As far as I know, `set` is also compatible with `vi` which `let`, *as I assume*, is not.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Good point!

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`:set` is for setting *options*, `:let` for assigning a value to a *variable*.

It happens that the value for an option is linked to the name of the option prepended by a `&` (the `&option-name` construct then behaves very similar to "ordinary" variables). So, the following are equivalent:

```
:set  tw=40
:let &tw=40
```

But, for example, assigning 50 to the global variable foo (`:let g:foo=50`) cannot be achieved with a `:set` command (because g:foo is a variable and not an option).

Some options are boolean like. When setting these, no value is needed (as in `:set noic` and the opposite `:set ic`).

Answer (score 26):

`:set` only works with options, and [sehe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9990809/1743811) showcases some good usage examples.

`:let` on the other hand can do almost everything that `:set` can do, plus more. It can assign a value to

- a variable, e.g. `let vi = 'vim'`
- an option, e.g. `let &tw = 40`
- a register, e.g. `let @a = $HOME . '/vimfiles'`
- an environment variable, e.g. `let $NOTHING = 'NOTHING'`

Another major difference is that the right hand side of `:let` is an *expression*, meaning you can do things like string concatenation (as seen in my register example above) and arithmetic operations (e.g. `let &tw = 40 + 60`). This also means that you have to quote the value if it's a string. `:set` on the other hand reads the value verbatim.

It's easier to use `:set` with options even though `:let` can also do most of it, Here are some comparison using [sehe's examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9990809/1743811) ("n/a" means no way to do it with `:let`)

- `:verbose set` vs n/a (don't think there's another way to list all options)
- `:set tw=40` vs `:let &tw = 40` (yes, you can use the same shorthand in `let` too)
- `:set wrap&` vs n/a
- `:set nowrap` vs `:let &wrap = 0` (for boolean options, 0 is false and 1 is true)
- `:set wrap!` vs `:let &wrap = !&wrap`

A few more examples

- print the value of an option: `:set formatoptions?` vs `:echo &formatoptions` (`let` doesn't print values, unlike `set`)
- assigning to multiple options at the same time:

  ```
  :set et sw=4 sts=4
  ```

  vs

  ```
  :let [&et, &sw, &sts] = [0, 4, 4]
  ```
- set global option: `setglobal et` vs `let &g:et = 1`
- set local option: `setlocal et` vs `let &l:et = 1`

See `:h :set` and `:h :let` for more details

---

## tl;dr

`:set` only works with options but the syntax is much simpler. `:let` works with not just options but also variables, registers, and environment variables. Unlike `:set`, the right hand side of `:let` is an expression.

Answer (score 25):

Set is a more user-friendly interface specialized for options

E.g.

```
:verbose set
```

to display all options in effect.

```
:set tw=40
```

Will work as a shorthand for `set textwidth=40`

```
:set wrap&
```

Will set the *default* value for option `wrap`

```
:set nowrap
```

Will unset the option

```
:set wrap!
```

Will *toggle* the option

Most importantly,

> `:set`<kbd>Tab</kbd>   # to get tab completion!

**Few of the above can (easily) be achieved with `let`.**

Comment: re: `:set nowrap`, options.txt (:help set-option) says:  

:se[t] {option}  Toggle option: set, switch it on.
   Number option: show value.
   String option: show value.  

This doesn't agree with what you have here, when you say 'will set the default value for option wrap'.  ??

Comment: @Ellipticalview I'm a little bit confused. You are quoting parts of the documentation. If you read the whole thing you'll find it agrees with all my cases. [Note: the `no`-prefixed options can be confusing. Also note `option&` has a trailing `&` that you may have missed.]

Comment: Very late upvote for saying set is more user-friendly instead of saying set is restricted. For me that was the missing piece.

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on what people have written about `:let`, I've noticed that it can be used to assign a value in a variable to an option, something `:set` can't do. For example, this function uses `let` to assign the value in the global variable `orig_tw` to the `textwidth`option:

```
" Toggle Autowrap
" Default of 72 but can be overridden by tw settings in other vimrc files
let g:orig_tw = 72
function Toggle_autowrap_mode()
    if &textwidth == 0
        " Must use let instead of set here in order for g:orig_tw to be
        " evaluated properly
        let &textwidth = g:orig_tw
        echo "Autowrap mode on tw=" . &textwidth
    else
        let g:orig_tw = &textwidth
        set textwidth=0
        echo "Autowrap mode off tw=" . &textwidth
    endif
endfunction

noremap _A :call Toggle_autowrap_mode()<CR>
```

Comment: **Summary:** `let` allows for assigning a variable to an option: `let &textwidth = g:orig_tw` and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple.
As people have said `set` is for options and works better because of the limitation. Also `set` is the historical command that all versions of `vi` use to set their options. Most (all?) other versions of `vi` don't have `let`.

But possibly most important is that `set` works on all versions of `vim`, the `let` command can be omitted when you compile `vim`. The standard `tiny` and `small` builds do this.

If it's missing `let` gives you the error:
`E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`

Note: `if` and `endif` are not implemented either in `vim.tiny` but in this case the commands do not give an error, instead everything between the two commands is skipped INCLUDING `else`.