# Update titlestring in Vim when I enter/leave the commandline

Tags: vim, xming

### Correct setting: add `|redraw` at the end

```
augroup CmdLineStatus_to_Title
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter * set titlestring=CommandlineMode|redraw
    autocmd CmdlineEnter * set titlestring=%F\ %{v:servername}\ %{mode()}
augroup END
```

---

### Original Post

I tried the following auto-command, and fail to achieve what I wanted. Ideally,
I would like to append to the end of the `titlestring` an identifier when I move
the cursor to the command line (by pressing `:` key).

```
" Global setting
setglobal titlestring=%F\ %{v:servername}\ %{mode()}

" The Auto command group
augroup CmdLineStatus_to_Title
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter * let &l:titlestring="CommandlineMode"
    " autocmd CmdlineLeave * let &l:titlestring=%F\ %{v:servername}\ %{mode()}
augroup END
```

There are multiple problems:

1. The `titlestring`, and/or the title of the Gvim window **does not update**
   when I **ENTER** the command line. It refreshes when I **LEAVE** the command
   line mode.

   - Also, the `&l:` flag did not restrict the setting native to the buffer: I get the constant title string as "CommandlineMode" for new files opened in new buffer/tabs. (One particular file is opened through a `nnoremap <> <Plug>VimwikiMakeDiaryNote` mapping, with no command line operation involved.)
2. Also, I cannot simply "append" a customized string towards the end of the
   `titlestring`. This should be a syntax problem

   - Also related: the line in `augroup` that has been commented out shall bring
     about the following error when I actually LEAVE the command line. Please
     also advise how to restore the `titlestring` settings when I leave the
     command line.

[image]

*Inspiration and credits*:

- Naumann in [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/may-i-have-a-vim-session-report-its-mode-in-its-window-title), I can already tell the `titlestring` the current mode of Vim.

**Machine specification**: the reported trouble occurred on Gvim running through
X11 on a WSL-Linux-shell on a Windows 10 machine. The `%{mode()}` "variable"
does update when I switch back and forth between the Normal mode and the Insert
mode.  Chances are this could be a Xming problem? Will test by updating
the Gvim.exe that is installed natively to the Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at [`:help 'titlestring'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27titlestring%27), you'll notice that this is a **global option**. As there is only a single window title for a Vim instance, local options don't make sense. You can update the contents based on the current window / buffer / whatever (using `:autocmd`), though.

---

Vim tries to avoid unnecessary screen updates. To force an update at a certain point in time [`:redraw`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Aredraw) can be used. The following works for me:

```
autocmd CmdlineEnter * set titlestring=CommandlineMode|redraw
```

---

Regarding your syntax error: As you use the `:let &option` syntax, the right-hand side must be a *Vim expression* (here: interpreted as a String), so you must enclose it in (single or double) quotes. The escaping of spaces with backslashes is for the `:set` command. This is easy to confuse :-)

Comment: Thank you thank you! I am forever confused by variables vs options. I bet things started with those variables & options that should share the same name, where both are claimed to have been internally linked or so. Wonder if you have a better reference than this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990219/vim-whats-the-difference-between-let-and-set?